# E-Mail cannot be sent when using an encrypted password

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would like to encrypt my password by `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

```java
@Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        var pw = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        System.out.println(pw.encode("my-password"));
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

When I run my application, the code above prints out the encoded password. So I stop my application, copy that string and paste it into application.yml, which looks like this:

```yaml
spring:
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: my-email@gmail.com
    password: "{bcrypt}$2a$10$FXSkpQloaZILb7ixYTD2P./yutuASulNhEQ1UVEodX7Ao0oGgcaFG"
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          starttls:
            enable: true
          auth: true
```

Then I run my application again, but then I get this error:

> jakarta.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and
> Password not accepted.

If the password is plain text only, it works fine. Why not when it's encrypted?

Comment: It's not like GMail knows how to decrypt your BCrypted password, y'know.  What are you interested in guarding against?  Were you going to commit this configuration into source control and you wouldn't want your password exposed?

Comment: ...because GMail does not know how to decrypt that. You cannot just come up with a custom way of sending data unless the counterparty is ready to receive it. There's no way to send your password specially encrypted in any way. Rather, GMail requires the whole connection to be done over TLS which means it will securely encrypt all data going to Google, including your password. Therefore you do not really need to encrypt it yourself. See e.g. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/240763 and https://security.stackexchange.com/a/146527.

Comment: @Makoto yes, my repository is public and I don't want anyone to see my password.

Comment: @PetrJaneček but if my password is plain, everyone will be able to see it. Isn't there a way to protect that password?

Comment: No, the connection to the Google server will be encrypted with TLS, meaning all data going to the server and coming from the server are encrypted. Nobody will be able to see your password except for you and the SMTP server.

Comment: 1.) as others have explained, this doesn't work. 2.) if, theoretically, it *did* work, then the encrypted password could be used to authenticate as you, so anyone who saw it wouldn't need to decrypt it, but could use it as-is, i.e. you wouldn't have gained anything anyway! The moral of the story is: you can not have private knowledge that your code needs to use but the person running the code can't see, that's just not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### bcrypt is a hashing function

bcrypt is a secure password-hashing function, not an encryption function.
The difference between hashing and encryption is that hashing is destructive, meaning that you aren't supposed to be able to "decrypt" the original password from a hash.

As such, there's nothing that Spring Boot can do with the password's hash. It's just treating it as a plain text password. In fact, if you change your account's password to `{bcrypt}$2a$10$FXSkpQloaZILb7ixYTD2P./yutuASulNhEQ1UVEodX7Ao0oGgcaFG` everything should work. Of course that this is doing absolutely nothing for security.

### Encrypted properties

If you want to store "opaque" but usable properties in your application you need encryption, not hashing.

A common solution to encrypt properties is Spring Boot is [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/). Although storing encrypted properties with the application code isn't really a good secure practice (see [Makoto's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75871628/664577) for more details on why this isn't a good idea).

Nevertheless, you can find documentation on how to integrate Jasypt and Spring Boot in the [jasypt-spring-boot](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot) project. With Jasypt you can encrypt values using a password (that you should then keep safe at all costs) and let the framework handle everything for you.

Assuming that you are using Maven to build the system, you can get started by adding the following dependency to the project's `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And then you can encrypt properties with Jasypt Maven Plugin:

```
mvn jasypt:encrypt-value -Djasypt.encryptor.password="the password that you should keep safe" -Djasypt.plugin.value="theValueYouWantToEncrypt"
```

Add the encrypted property to your application properties:

```
secret.property=ENC(nrmZtkF7T0kjG/VodDvBw93Ct8EgjCA+)
```

The property will be transparently decrypted and made available to your application in plain text.

### Better idea #1: Use a vault to manage secrets

From a security perspective I would recommend a different strategy. A vault (such as [Spring Cloud Vault](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/) and [HashiCorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/)) is a good way to store secrets such as SMTP credentials. A vault is much safer and easier to manage than manually encrypting properties / manually inputing security keys around. You can find a guide on how to configure Spring Boot to read properties from a Vault in Spring Boot's [vault Configuration guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/vault-config/).

You can even abstract secret management away from your application. E.g., if you are using a tool such as [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) you can delegate secret management to it.

### Better Idea #2: The application shouldn't be directly aware of SMTP.

An even better idea is to never share SMTP credentials with the application to begin with. There are tons of great e-mail delivery services with modern APIs to properly send emails. Managed services can make your life much easier as a developer. There's way more to emails than meets the eye, and I would personally avoid the hassle if possible. Have a look at services such as [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/), [MailGun](https://www.mailgun.com/) and [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/).

**In short**

- bcrypt is a hash function, not an encryption function
- You can encrypt your application properties but you probably shouldn't
- Secrets should be stored somewhere safe, such as a vault
- There are ways to abstract secret management from the application. As a rule of thumb, the less that your application has to know about secrets the better.
- Speaking about abstracting complexity away from your application, your application may be better off not knowing anything about SMTP to begin with.

Comment: In the abstract, using Vault would still require you to pass in the necessary token or AppRole, and depending on where you're deploying it's kinda six of one and half-a-dozen of the other...

Comment: @Makoto, at some point there will be a token somewhere, you are correct. Nevertheless, sharing a token (that can be specific for a certain machine, short lived, easily rotated, and secured by strong RBAC / ABAC rules) is still a good idea.
While I support your answer (and have upvoted it), truth be told, it generally doesn't take a lot of effort for someone to find a decrypted secret in the command line history, environment variables or K8's mounted volumes. Assuming that I'm running the software, I certainly rather deal with a leaked token rather than leaked SMTP credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put your password into your source control.

Explicitly leave the property blank, or omit it entirely, and leave some documentation floating around specifying that - as a runtime parameter - the password needs to be specified.

You can do so pretty easily in Spring, passing it as a parameter.

```
java -jar your-app.jar --spring.mail.password=xxx
```

Depending on your needs in local development, [Spring Boot offers an array of options](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) on where you can place your configuration and what precedence it can have, if you want to keep it out of source control.  I do personally prefer the parameters, but you could also set environment variables and they'd work the same.  Or, you could [go the DevTools route](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools.globalsettings) as well.

Encrypting it here buys you nothing since you'll have to decrypt it on its way to GMail, and to decrypt it, you have to know what secret you used to decrypt it, which - if you just left embedded in your code would quickly [turn into turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down) since you'd have to secure every key except the last one, and then you can just work backwards to get them all, anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good approach! But my problem is that I need that password all the time, and when I commit and push my source and accidentally don't omit the password, it could be too late. So I think, a better way could be using another yml file that is on .gitignore. That file contains the password only and gets imported into application.yml.

Comment: @xRay, no need for another yml file. If you are not worried about storing the plain text password, there are plenty plenty of ways to externalise Spring configuration (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config). The easiest is probably OS Environment Variables (e.g., `SPRING_MAIL_PASSWORD`).

Comment: @xRay:  I've included a few extra locations that Spring looks for this kind of info.  Yes, it might mean another properties file floating around somewhere.  But, that's preferable to the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you just sent an encrypted string in the form of a password.
The password in spring.mail.password is used as plain text

In this case, if you want to encrypt passwords in your spring boot application, you need to use, for example, the Jasypt. [Jasypt example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt).

with Jasypt you can store your secrets (passwords) in encrypted form, and you can set the decryption key to an environment variable as an example

Comment: Will Gmail decrypt it, if I use Jasypt?

Comment: If you configure Jasypt correctly your secrets will be automatically decrypted on startup.I advise you to look through either the documentation or guides on using Jasypt, there are also analogues of Jasypt

Comment: The OP is asking for a way to _send_ the password securely. What you're suggesting is how to _store_ it sort-of securely locally for the application to load it at run-time. Those are two separate things.

Comment: That's right, these are two different things. In the example question, why is Bcrypt used to encrypt the properies of the file, my answer was aimed at giving a correct understanding of what to use.The question, like the error itself, is related to the fact that in the property file the specified password is sent in encrypted form and therefore an error occurs.